# Raster to ASCII -9999 for all cells!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, table

I am trying to simply get the value of each cell in my raster using the Raster To ASCII tool in ArcGIS Desktop.  I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong. The output I get is all -9999 when the input rasters are float with a range of values of about -3 to 35. If I use Raster To Point then I get the actual values to the points, but I need these data in matrix/table form.  What the heck am I doing wrong, I have tried everything that I can possibly think of!

Comment: How do you know if it's all -9999? Re-import to see if this is a case. Or simply search for 3 in notepad.

Comment: There may be a better way than converting to ASCII. What do you hope to do with the raw values?

Comment: Hi @FelixIPif I open it in or outside of GIS, I can see that all values are -9999 and a search for a number like 3 confirms this as well.

Comment: @Aaron I am trying to get all of the elevation values in a matrix form so that I can perform analyses elevation change across four periods with simulated elevation data from a model.  I have four rasters from different years and I ultimately will need to get the elevation of each of these rasters at different times to use as benchmarks in comparing the output of a model for accuracy. So having the data in a matrix or excell form where cell 1,1 is the same spot in space in all the rasters and the simulated landscape is critical.

Comment: Depending on how your rasters are originally created you might want to look at the environment settings related to snap to cell and cell size as another way to assure your cells stack exactly on top of each other.

Comment: The issue appears to have lied with my clipping of the rasters.  Raster to ASCII worked without any issues on the full, unclipped rasters.  I think there must have been some sort of issue with the shp that I used to perform the clip.  I made a new shp of the same clip extent and re-clipped and then Raster to ASCII worked.